# Error en migración con Foreign Key, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Tengo estas migraciones en un proyecto de laravel 5.8 , en una creo la tabla Users y en la otra user_profiles , en la segunda pongo una Foreign Key del campo "user_id" al campo "id" de la tabla "users"

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}



public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unique();
        $table->integer('age')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
}
```

El error obtenido es el siguiente

> Migrating: 2015_10_12_000000_create_user_profiles_table
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `portal`.`#sql-4cc8_70` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `user_pro
>   files` add constraint `user_profiles_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las llaves foráneas no deben contener valores negativos, razón por la cual te da el error que tienes ahí.

**Solucion:** Debes de agregar `unsigned()` a tu llave foreanea.

```
Schema::create('user_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('age')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
})
```

No estoy seguro que `unique` tenga que estar ahí, pero puedes hacer lo siguiente si en realidad lo deseas:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->unique();
```

Comment: Gracias , me faltava el unsigned()

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) la declaración de tu llave foránea debe ser de este tipo

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

Y posteriormente indicar la vinculación con la llave primaria de este modo

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Nadamás como un punto extra, es que desde [Laravel 5.8](https://laraveldaily.com/be-careful-laravel-5-8-added-bigincrements-as-defaults/) el tipo de dato por defecto asignado a una migración en la llave primaria es de tipo `bigIncrements()`.

Entonces solo revisar este punto al momento de crear las migraciones y crear las relaciones entre ellas